# How to calculate the sum of variables from JSON data?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I wrote a project where the string is returned the other way around.

```
@PostMapping("/reverse")
public String reverseList(@RequestBody String string) {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string.split("[+,]"));
    return  IntStream.range(0, stringList.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> stringList.get(stringList.size() - 1 - i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("+"));
}
```

**Command through curl :**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "a1+a2+a3+a4" localhost:8080/hello/reverse
```

Output :

```
a4+a3+a2+a1
```

How can I change so that I can add values. For example, when returning

```
а1 = 10
а2 = 10
a3 = 10
```

And when I write the command below :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "a1+a2+a3" localhost:8080/hello/reverse
```

It should return the sum as 30.

Comment: Why you do not put an entity as RequestBody instead of String?

Comment: told to do using json

Comment: let's say in the output, so that I can put a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this. It will make your work easier.

Send `a1=10+a2=10+a3=10` instead of `a1+a2+a3` in the curl command.

Command :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "a1=10+a2=10+a3=10" localhost:8080/hello/reverse
```

Update the code to this :

```
@PostMapping("/reverse")
public String reverseList(@RequestBody String str) {
    int sum = 0;
    String[] variables = str.split("\\+");
    for (String variable : variables) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(variable.split("=")[1]);
    }
    return String.valueOf(sum); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you How can you simply calculate the entire amount, for example, if I write in the terminal = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4. Gotta print 10

Comment: Then, just do `sum += Integer.parseInt(value)` in the loop after splitting.